# SQL Server Agent - String or binary data would truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am working on SQL replication and facing some issues. I am now trying to enable output logging for replication by adding the following commands to the Merge agent under SQL Server Agent.

```
-Output C:\ReplOutput.txt -OutputVerboseLevel 2
```

However, when I try to run the agent again it fails and gives me below error:

> String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001] (Error 8152)

It works fine when I remove those commands but I need them for error logging and checking issues in my replication.

Comment: if it fails immeditaley,can you run profiler to see what are the statements being run.I dont  think this failure has to do with enabling logging

Comment: Try pointing it to another location other than C:. May be to desktop.